# MYSQL From 2 tables Where x from table1 and y from table2

Tags: mysql, select

Hi Struggling with query from 2 tables as per below:

```
table1
id    qid    comment
 1     2       test1
 2     1       test2
 3     3       test2

table2
id   question  enabled
 2      a       1
 1      b       2
 9      c       1
 3      d       1
```

What I am trying to do is get list of result with comment (table1) WHERE table2 id enabled=1

Column qid from table 1 and id from table 2 is matching.

Any suggestions please.

Expected result:

```
id    qid    comment
 1     2       test1
 3     3       test2
```

Comment: `JOIN` the two tables and then use your `WHERE`.

Comment: Post the exact result you expect based on your data sample.

Comment: Apologies, qid (table1) and id (table2) are matching

Comment: Then please refer to my two remaining  comments.

Comment: So looking at the updated tables now and what I am expecting to see in Expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you need to `join` these two tables and then apply `where` clause on `enabled` column

```
SELECT a.id as id,
a.qid as qid,
a.comment as comment 
FROM table1 as a
JOIN table2 as b
ON a.qid=b.id
WHERE b.enabled=1;
```